# offline location tracking

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I want to draw employee's live location and traveled path ,

I am running a service in background continuously to get location details and storing to server , at admin side I am drawing the path by those records stored in db.

I am getting the path like  a square in offline while am able to clearly in online

[image]

how can i store the correct lat long values in server in offline,

I want to draw the path clearly in offline also ,how can I achieve that, please suggest me a way, thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "online/offline"? And in "offline" you are getting correct info but you are storing incorrect one, or are you getting incorrect info to begin with?

Comment: offline means with out internet , am using fused location provider

Comment: You should still be able to get location updates without an internet connection, what you can do is check value for [getAccuracy()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#getAccuracy()) for locations you obtain

Answer (score 1):

Create a local `Database` and store `locations` in it. Whenever internet connected send these values to server. You can `draw path` from local Db or Server values.